# Site URL has been been identified as malicious and/or abusive -- Facebook error

Tags: facebook

I was creating an app for the first time, on a new domain I purchased, and I get the message "Site URL has been been identified as malicious and/or abusive."

Now I am just installing software at this point to the site, and getting things setup, so I am at least getting this message for something I have not done.  How can I get a review from facebook or how can I get this status removed for my url?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably it is not your site or url but the hosting you are using. It may be that another site hosted in the same server is the one with malicious software

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook support.

Comment: But the guys at facebook support says its about the implementation (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/505594746176481). I'm having the same issue. I was testing my main application url by pointing to my app engine subdomains. How can I ask facebook to make it clean again. Is there a page to send an appeal?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article in [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/caroltice/2013/03/15/when-facebook-calls-you-abusive-reclaim-your-reputation/) about how to reclaim your reputation after Facebook have tagged your site as malicious.

Basically search the sitemap of your web and check if some of the links are headed to malicious content.