# Facebook app shows doamin as "This url has been identified as malicious and/or abusive"

Tags: facebook

I am new to facebook app. I have just purchased one domain and trying to integrate facebook login with my website. My website is with SSL. I have purchased SSL even. But when I try to add domain in App Platform it gives me error as "This url has been identified as malicious and/or abusive".

I am not able to understand how this is possible. Is there any way out to remove this error or to contact facebook for same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396284/site-url-has-been-been-identified-as-malicious-and-or-abusive-facebook-error

Answer (score -1):

Website name and details should follow all the terms and conditions of Facebook.

Comment: I have checked it.. I don't find terms and conditions are getting violated in any manner..

Answer (score -1):

Solution according to: https://www.forbes.com/sites/caroltice/2013/03/15/when-facebook-calls-you-abusive-reclaim-your-reputation/

First go to: https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/

and check if your URL appears as non safe or as Untested

Click on reclassify --> url reclassification request

Then select the option SAFE

Suggest a category

Add your email

click the button to proceed, then go to yuour email and click the link that trendmicro sent to you, then wait

other links: https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/index.php

https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/about/legal/detection-reevaluation.html